fetchone возвращает NoneType (не смог нигде найти решение)
в файле db.py:
import sqlite3
import os

class Database:
 def __init__(self, db_file):
     current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

     self.db_file = os.path.join(current_dir, db_file)

     self.connection = sqlite3.connect(self.db_file)
     self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

     self.cursor.execute("""
               CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                   user_id INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                   referer_id INTEGER,
                   rewards INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
                   referals INTEGER DEFAULT 0
               )
           """)
     self.connection.commit()

 def user_exists(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
        return bool(len(result))


 def add_user(self, user_id, referer_id=None):
    with self.connection:
        if referer_id != None:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id', 'referer_id') VALUES (?,?)", (user_id, referer_id,)).fetchone()
        else:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,)).fetchone()



 def get_rewards(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        sql = "SELECT 'rewards' FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?"
        print(f"Запрос: {sql}, Аргумент:{user_id}")
        result = self.cursor.execute(sql, (user_id,)).fetchone()
        print(result)
        print(user_id)
        if result is not None:
            return result
        else:
            return 0

 def add_rewards(self, user_id, amount):
    with self.connection:
        current_rewards = self.get_rewards(user_id)
        self.cursor.execute(
            "UPDATE 'users' SET 'rewards' = ? WHERE 'user_id' = ?",
            (current_rewards + amount, user_id))
        self.connection.commit()

и в другом файле я его применяю:
from asyncio import sleep
from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.types import Message
from handlers.db import Database
import os


router = Router()
curretn_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db_path = os.path.join(curretn_path, 'database.db')

db = Database(db_path)

@router.message(F.text == 'Бросок')
async def command_start(message: Message):
    data = await message.answer_dice(emoji='')
    await sleep(3.5)
    if data.dice.value == 6:
        db.add_rewards(message.from_user.id, 10)
        await message.answer("Хороший бросок! Вам начислено 10 монет.")
    else:
        await message.answer("Хорошая попытка! Попробуйте ещё раз")

в консоли принтами я получаю:
Запрос: SELECT 'rewards' FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?, Аргумент:628072647
None
628072647
Везде пишут о проверке на наличие результата, что в моем коде есть, но как быть, если fetchone всегда возвращает None? все 3 файла я положил в одну папку, что бы не было ошибок с путями

во второй вставке кода применяется, даже если не применил, это ведь не отменяет того факта, что в get_rewards fetchone возвращает None

Хотя на самом деле даже с вызовом add_rewards будет тоже непонятно — в показанном вами коде нет ни одного INSERT-запроса, а значит и нет никаких причин для появления строчек в базе. То ли вы показали не весь код, то ли вы просто ещё не научились работать с sql

да, я показал не весь код, что бы показать конкретную проблему, где она возникает, во втором файле создается экземпляр класса Database, затем обработка сообщения, где применяется функция экземпляр коасса.add_rewards(message.from_user.id)

Ну значит нужно какое-то объяснение, почему вы вообще считаете это проблемой — почему вы решили, что fetchone должен выдавать не None?

в файле db.py класс Database, где создается таблица со столбцами (id, user_id, referrer_id, rewards), rewards имеет дефолтное значение 0, к которому я обращаюсь в функции get_rewards и получив значение из конкретной ячейки, делаю с ним арифметические действия, но get_rewards возвращает None, а не число

Ничего из описанного вами не приводит к появлению строчек в базе, а значит и нет никаких причин, почему fetchone должен был бы возвращать не None

поправил, вставил весь код из 2х файлов, если подскажете что сделал не так, буду благодарен

Уберите .fetchone() из всех концов строк с execute. Где INSERT, там .fetchone() вообще не нужен. А после execute где SELECT попробуйте сделать отдельной следующей строкой result = self.cursor.fetchone(). Может и не поможет, а может и поможет.

к сожалению, не помогло(

Нашел свою ошибку в sql запросах, вместо:
SELECT 'rewards' FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?

UPDATE 'users' SET 'rewards' = ? WHERE 'user_id' = ?

необходимо было писать без обертывания названий столбцов в '', т.е.:
SELECT rewards FROM users WHERE user_id = ?

UPDATE users SET rewards = ? WHERE user_id = ?

всем спасибо за помощь!
